# how to draw polygon including negative points ? in C#

Tags: c#

i am doing c# project. i have found a problem and unable to find answer of this problem that's why i am posting here/
i am implementing procedural floor plan generation in c#. at first i need to draw a polygon to on given points to generate grid. points can be positive or negative. points will be in floating.

From the Microsoft Documentation i am able to draw polygon for the floating positive points, but when i change points to negative it does not draw anything on form.

this method id drawing x,y coordinates 0,0 in the corner .

code example
public void DrawPolygonPointF(PaintEventArgs e)
{

```
// Create pen.
Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

// Create points that define polygon.
PointF point1 = new PointF(50.0F,  50.0F);
PointF point2 = new PointF(100.0F,  25.0F);
PointF point3 = new PointF(200.0F,   5.0F);
PointF point4 = new PointF(250.0F,  50.0F);
PointF point5 = new PointF(300.0F, 100.0F);
PointF point6 = new PointF(350.0F, 200.0F);
PointF point7 = new PointF(250.0F, 250.0F);
PointF[] curvePoints =
         {
             point1,
             point2,
             point3,
             point4,
             point5,
             point6,
             point7
         };

// Draw polygon curve to screen.
e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(blackPen, curvePoints);
```

}

i have negative coordinates value for example pointF(300,-250) this method is not drawing nothing for negative coordinates value.
So please give me brief solution because i don't know much about drawing.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: you mean you need to draw a diagram where 0,0 is in the middle of the window, not in a corner? Can't you just add an offset to the numbers as you plot them to represent the area you're viewing in the window, and / or scale the values too?

Comment: i have positive as well as negative points to draw polygon.

Comment: I guess you should provide some code, describe its results and what you expected from it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'negative points' - with some x,y coordinates with negative values? If 0,0 is the corner of your form where would you expect Windows to put these points when it plots them? (Or are you expecting the side of the polygon to be clipped, and that's not happening?)

Comment: what should i do ? how to put x,y  coordinates 0,0 in the center ?

Comment: you are right .i have negative x,y coordinates value and i want to handle them . i want to change x,y coordinates in the form center not in the corner.

Comment: Look at the answer @pquest. Add the x and y values from his calculation to each of your points to center the drawing.

Comment: TranslateTransform is the answer. Do not manipulate the data but the Graphics viewport!

Answer (score 2):

In C# 0,0 is the top left corner of the screen. So negative values are off the left or top edge of your form. You need to transform your coordinates from your coordinate space to the form's. To place 0,0 dead center, you would do this:

```
int screenX = myX + windowWidth / 2;
int screenY = myY + windowHeight / 2;
```

Comment: Just to give a little helpful nudge to people that don't know what is meant by "transform", it means to take these x and y values and add them to each of your points, or use an actual GDI transformation, but that is a little more complex.  This will slide (translate transform) your points so that they are relative to the center of the window.

Comment: If you want more information about doing a "real" GDI transofrmation, it can be found on MSDN at the following link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a1d65f4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ShHuzaifa yes, every point needs to be translated by these values.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Why mess with the data when can adapt the viewport?? Graphics.TranslateTranform and maybe Graphics.ScaleTransform is what is called for.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of the answer @pquest gave, and your newly added sample code, doing a "real" GDI transformation would look like this:

```
// Create pen.
Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

// Create points that define polygon.
PointF point1 = new PointF(50.0F,  50.0F);
PointF point2 = new PointF(100.0F,  25.0F);
PointF point3 = new PointF(200.0F,   5.0F);
<...snip...>

//Apply a translation Transformation to move 0,0 to the center of the 
//window.  You can now draw your points with negative values, without doing 
//any addition to them.
int screenX = windowWidth / 2;
int screenY = windowHeight / 2;
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform((float) screenX, (float) screenY);

// Draw polygon curve to screen.
e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(blackPen, curvePoints);
```

GDI Transformations are very powerful.  You can use them to move points around, flip points horizontally or vertically, scale things bigger or smaller, distort like a parallelogram,  and even do rotations.  All of these can be combined in to what is called a transformation matrix to get some very cool results.
More examples can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a1d65f4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: what is the value of myX,myY ?

Comment: Ahh, sorry, that doesn't belong there.  I forgot the remove it from pquest's code.  I've updated by answer.

Comment: what is the value of  windoWwidth and windowHeight ?

Comment: They are the width and height of your window, since the center of 1/2 its width and height.

Comment: `this.ClientSize.Width` and `this.ClientSize.Height` will probably be the easiest way to get them.

Comment: i am doing int windowWidth=this.width and int windowHeight=this.height.

Comment: That will probably be just fine, though width and height count the window border and title bar.  That means your Y values won't be exactly centered, but it will only be off by a small amount.

Answer (score 2):

That's working for me to this problem.
you just need to add couple lines of code in your code.

```
 int windowWidth = this.ClientSize.Width;
 int windowHeight = this.ClientSize.Height;
 int screenX = windowWidth / 2;
 int screenY = windowHeight / 2;
 e.Graphics.TranslateTransform((float)screenX, (float)screenY);
```